# How can I set up an infinite loop?

Tags: python

I want to set up a loop that never ends.

Is it **better** `while true` or `while 1==1`?

Language: Python.

Comment: What would you define as being "better"?

Comment: More efficient.

Comment: It’s pretty obvious that `True` is more "efficient" than `1==1`, in any context you could come with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1==1 simply evaluates to True, so rather get right to it and use

```
while True
```